# Whatsapp sharing link page doesn't exist

Tags: html, whatsapp

I doing a button to share a link to WhatsApp but after I clicked my button, the WhatsApp web shows the message "We couldn't find the page you were looking for".

this is my code

```
<a target="_blank" ng-href="https://wa.me/?text=aaa" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"></a>
```

after clicked my button, the URL

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/resolve?deeplink=/%3Ftext%3Daaa
```

May I know why the Whatsapp web show the message?

Comment: Does this page really exists? Maybe you need authorization for that? From where you receive this link?

Comment: after I clicked my code, it brings me to the URL

Comment: Yes, I know how URL works. But it seems that `?text=aaa` is invalid and points to non existing resource

Comment: but I just wanna test the share some message to WhatsApp, am I do anything wrong here?

Comment: Yes, if it's not working, then you are doing something wrong. E.g. missing phone number in url: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Comment: I'm getting "We couldn't find the page you were looking for" with any Whatsapp link, even their example of "https://wa.me/?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing`" listed here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

Comment: Ya, I'm also using this document and the document shows can use without the phone number in URL: "pre-filled message, use https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext", I using this method without phone number one. But if I put a specific phone number it works, for my case i dont want put a phone number

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, but..
It seems like Whatsapp broke this functionality a while ago. Only these kinds of texts with numbers are working at the moment.

(Was using the same functionality on my own site, have not found a proper replacement yet that works in all places/devices)

Comment: This answer is not sufficiently good. Please, read Stack Overflow instructions to have standard response and question.

Comment: @Rann I fixed this issue, I change the href to ```https://api.whatsapp.com/send/text?=aaa```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the href url to `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/text?=aaa`.